# ArrayAdapter in Android Studio

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to work on my `ListView` using `ArrayAdapter`. My question is why can't I use the `activity_main.xml` for the `ArrayAdapter` and why should I add a new .xml while there is nothing inside the new .xml?

Answer (score 1):

You need a new .xml file only if you have to create custom design. If you have to display only a text (One or 2 lines) you can use default layouts. The activity_main.xml is the layout of your activity. It has nothing to do with your listview.The new .xml file shows the layout for how the list is going to appear in your main activity.

Comment: Create custom message ? What is the example ? If I want to display names list (more than 2 lines), I need new .xml rite ?

Comment: If you need only names you don't need a new xml file. Here is an example http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/UI/UsingSimpleAdaptertofilldatatoListView.htm